# cube image not looking good in 3d animation

Tags: jquery, html, css, css-transitions

How can I make the cube perfect on the outside by rounding the corners of the cube I see some additional space how can I remove the additional space outside the cube.
http://jsfiddle.net/ZrpLT/3/

```
<div class="top" style="-webkit-transform: rotateX(90deg) translateZ(75px); z-index: 1000;"><img src="http://www.defie.co/designerImages/thumbnails/inventory.png" width="150" height="150" style="margin-top: 0px;"></div>


div.melonhtml5_gallery div.cube {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -o-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -ms-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1s;
    -moz-transition: -moz-transform 1s;
    -o-transition: -o-transform 1s;
    -ms-transition: -moz-transform 1s;
```

}

Comment: Please make a reduced test case, don't just drop your entire page's code into the jsFiddle HTML panel. The CSS and JavaScript panels are there for a reason. I'd try to help, but my CPU went crazy before I could figure from where I should disable the animations.

Comment: thanks for your reply...updated my fiddle....can u tell how to fix it....http://jsfiddle.net/ZrpLT/33/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make better fitting images. That seems to be all you could possibly do with a cube with sharp edges - the only kind you can (now) achieve with CSS rotation.

Also - your last cube won't rotate: http://jsfiddle.net/ZrpLT/25/

Who knows why, since MelonHTML5 3D Cube Gallery is a commercial product and it doesn't seem to have freely available documentation.

Placing `<div data-caption="void" data-image="" style="display:none"></div>` after the last box doesn't seem to do anything. And if you omit the `style="display:none"`, then - although the then-last cube now rotates - it leaves you with an additional ugly invisible box with shadow.

Comment: thanks for your reply....can you tell me what kind of image should i need to ask the designer